# If there is %ld or or even %lld, why do we use %d or even %hd?

Tags: c, types

I have learned C by self-taught, and I think since `%ld` can be used for the longer number, I have no idea why there are `%d`, and for a shorter one, `%hd`, or suchlike?

I also want to know how C specifiers works, why we need different specifier for numerical data types with different range since each data types has limit the range?

Comment: Google it. You will get the answers.

Comment: You use `%d` to print an `int` when you pass an `int`; you use `%ld` when you pass a `long`, and `%lld` when you pass a `long long`.  You can use `%hd` to limit the range to that of a `short`; the `int` will be converted to `short` before being printed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it now

Comment: Are you asking about `printf()` or `scanf()`?  Please do not say both as that  makes this broad question even more broad.

Comment: I don't know that each specifier acts differently on different function, I would like to talk about the 'printf()' one.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it you are talking about the print function? Or some other function that takes similar parameters.

It's to do with the primitive types, for example:
`int` can hold a number that is less than 16 bits.
Where as a `long` can hold 32 bits.
Then there is a `long long` that can hold 64 bits.

It all depends on the primitive you are using, it's quite easy to find how many bits a primitive holds. You also have to be careful when and where you use them as the user may not have a powerful enough computer to run it. There is also the fact that some versions of C may not have a particular primitive, this maybe down to age or even optimisation of a modified C system.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `printf(const char *format, ...)` takes arbitrary types after the format and an arbitrary number of values.  An `int` typically takes up less space than `long long`.

`printf()` uses the `format` to determine what argument follows.  If the specifiers do not match the types passed, undefined behavior.

```
long long ll = 12345678;
int i = 4321;
printf("%lld %d\n", ll, i);  // Format matches the type and count of arguments passed.
                             // Result: values printed as text as expected
printf("%d %d %d\n", ll, i); // Format mis-matches the type and count of arguments
                             // Result: undefined behavior
```

---

`"%hd"` `"%hdd"` involve another mechanism.  C, long ago, decided that when using small types like `short` and `signed char` are used, they would first go though *integer promotions* to `int` before further processing (some exceptions exist).  So for a function like `printf()`, when passed a `short`, that value is converted to an `int` first.  `printf()` does not know if the `int` it receives was originally an `int` or `short`.  In that case the following is OK.

```
int i = 4321;
short s = 321;

printf("%hd %d\n", i, i);  // Format matches the promoted type
printf("%hd %d\n", s, s);  // Format matches the promoted type
```

When `printf()` encounters `"%hd"`, it expect to receive an `int`, but it will internally convert that `int` value to a `short` value before printing.